# How shorthand works in Java

Tags: java, shorthand

I cannot find valid syntax for java shorthand.

How should i rewrite in shorthand this thing:

```
     int a = 2, b=4;
        if(a < 4) {
        System.out.println("a < b");}
    else { System.out.println("a >= b");
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "shorthand"? That's not a technical term within the Java language.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what the problem is?

Comment: You just don't know the subject.

Comment: I think you should find a good book for Java (or rather programming in general) and it take it from there...

Comment: You can shorten above to: `System.out.println(a < b ? "a < b" : "b >= a")`. I don't know if you meant this by `shorthand`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "shortest hand" I can imagine is something like:

```
 String s = (a < 4) ? "a<b" : "a>=b";
 System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 7):

I *suspect* you're after the [*conditional operator*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

```
System.out.println(a < b ? "a < b" : "a >= b");
```

If that's not what you were looking for, please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println("a"+((a<b)?"<":">=")+"b")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 2, b=4;
System.out.println((a < 4) ? "a < b" : "a>=b");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for sake of answer, another version of short-hand

```
System..out.println("a " + (a < 4 ? "<" : ">=") + " b");
```